# Increasing memory available for swapping on RAM using the zram.sh file on Raspberry OS

Tags: bash, opencv, memory-management, raspberry-pi

I'm not too familiar with bash scripting, butI'm trying to increase the swap memory for my pi to run opencv 4.5.0 on it.

This is the zram.sh file available on my pc:

```
!/bin/bash

export LANG=C

cores=$(nproc --all)

# disable zram
core=0
while [ $core -lt $cores ]; do
    if [[ -b /dev/zram$core ]]; then
        swapoff /dev/zram$core
    fi
    let core=core+1
done
if [[ -n $(lsmod | grep zram) ]]; then
    rmmod zram
fi
if [[ $1 == stop ]]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

and the tutorial that I'm following has this as their zram.sh file:
[image: Turorial's zram.sh file]

I'd really appreciate some help with this

Comment: So, what's the problem or question here? You just show two scripts, that may work or may not work, and don't really give enough information on what the problem is and, if something is not working, then how you expect it to work. Could you please add more information?

Comment: I asking what modifications I can make to the top script to increase the memory factor of my ram by (x3) like the script on the bottom. 
These are supposedly both ram.sh files. the one top was what I found on my pc and the one on the bottom was part of a setup tutorial off the web.

Comment: The thing is the first script, the way it is in the question, only disables zram, and doesn't have any code to enable it. The second script only enables it. Do you have zram-tools installed?